# TSQL Counting number of Consecutive Absences in a row

Tags: t-sql, subquery

*Problem:** I'm trying to calculate the number of consecutive absence each student have for a particular class. However, the count need to be restarted if that student did attend class for one day.

e.g. If class **MATH1234** has classes on Monday and Friday and student **001234** missed Monday, Friday for Week 1 and Monday for Week 2 but attended Friday for Week 2, then missed Monday and Friday for Week 3, their consecutive absence count for that class would be:

(this is a cut down version of my Lessons table)

> ```
> Class Day Week    IsAbsent    ConsecutiveAbs
> MATH1234  Mon 1   1       1
> MATH1234  Fri 1   1       2
> MATH1234  Mon 2   1       3
> MATH1234  Fri 2   0       0
> MATH1234  Mon 3   1       1
> MATH1234  Fri 3   1       2
> ```

I have a table called **Lessons** that contain a running list of all the students and the classes they are enrolled in and whether they were absent for any classes:

**Lessons**([Student ID], [Class Number], [Line Number], [Academic Period], [Year], [Term], [Week], [Day Period], [ClassDate], [IsAbsent], [ReasonCode], [ConsecutiveAbs])

Given the table above, what I am currently doing is Updating the Lessons table change the value of ConsecutiveAbs like this:

```
UPDATE Lessons
SET ConsecutiveAbs = 
(SELECT ISNULL(SUM(CAST(IsAbsent AS numeric)), 0)
 FROM Lessons AS L3
 WHERE L3.IsAbsent = 1
 AND L1.IsAbsent <> 0
 AND L3.[Student ID] = L1.[Student ID]
 AND L3.[Class Number] = L1.[Class Number]
 AND L3.[Line Number] = L1.[Line Number]
 AND L3.[Year] = L1.[Year]
 AND L3.[ClassDate] <= L1.[ClassDate]
 AND (L3.[ClassDate] > (SELECT MAX(L2.ClassDate)
      FROM Lessons AS L2
      WHERE L2.IsAbsent = 0
      AND L2.[Student ID] = L1.[Student ID]
      AND L2.[Class Number] = L1.[Class Number]
      AND L2.[Line Number] = L1.[Line Number]
      AND L2.[Year] = L1.[Year]
      AND L2.ClassDate < L1.[ClassDate]
 ) OR (SELECT MAX(L2.ClassDate)
       FROM Lessons AS L2
       WHERE L2.IsAbsent = 0
       AND L2.[Student ID] = L1.[Student ID]
       AND L2.[Class Number] = L1.[Class Number]
       AND L2.[Line Number] = L1.[Line Number]
       AND L2.[Year] = L1.[Year]
       AND L2.ClassDate < L1.[ClassDate]
 ) IS NULL))
 FROM Lessons AS L1
```

But that disregard the classes where the student actually attended the class and just kept counting :(

> ```
> Class Day Week    IsAbsent    ConsecutiveAbs
>
> MATH1234  Mon 1   1       1
> MATH1234  Fri 1   1       2
> MATH1234  Mon 2   1       3
> MATH1234  Fri 2   0       4
> MATH1234  Mon 3   1       5
> MATH1234  Fri 3   1       6
> ```

Any idea?

Comment: possible duplicate of [TSQL Counting number of Consecutive Absence in a row within time period](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5386158/tsql-counting-number-of-consecutive-absence-in-a-row-within-time-period)

Comment: Actually no. Similar, but not the same.

Comment: Since you had problem with my solution, I modified it. Please try again. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Similar to the answer to your previous question, only this time it looks for a class that has been attended, instead of just limiting the search by a week.

```
UPDATE allLessons
SET ConsecutiveAbs = results.ConsecutiveAbs
FROM 
    Lessons allLessons JOIN
(
    SELECT 
        LessonsAbsent.[Student ID],
        LessonsAbsent.[Class Number],
        LessonsAbsent.[Line Number],
        LessonsAbsent.[Year],
        LessonsAbsent.ClassDate,
        ISNULL(SUM(CAST(IsAbsent AS numeric)), 0) AS ConsecutiveAbs
    FROM 
        Lessons LessonsAbsent JOIN
        Lessons RunningTotalAbsent ON 
            RunningTotalAbsent.IsAbsent = 1
            AND LessonsAbsent.[Student ID] = RunningTotalAbsent.[Student ID]
            AND LessonsAbsent.[Class Number] = RunningTotalAbsent.[Class Number]
            AND LessonsAbsent.[Line Number] = RunningTotalAbsent.[Line Number]
            AND LessonsAbsent.[Year] = RunningTotalAbsent.[Year]
            AND LessonsAbsent.ClassDate >= RunningTotalAbsent.ClassDate

            -- Only include this date in the running total only if the student has not attended a class in-between the absences.
            AND NOT EXISTS (
                SELECT *
                FROM Lessons notAbsent
                WHERE 
                    LessonsAbsent.[Student ID] = notAbsent.[Student ID]
                    AND LessonsAbsent.[Class Number] = notAbsent.[Class Number]
                    AND LessonsAbsent.[Line Number] = notAbsent.[Line Number]
                    AND LessonsAbsent.[Year] = notAbsent.[Year]
                    AND notAbsent.IsAbsent = 0
                    AND notAbsent.ClassDate <= LessonsAbsent.ClassDate
                HAVING MAX(ClassDate) > RunningTotalAbsent.ClassDate
        )
    WHERE LessonsAbsent.IsAbsent = 1   
    GROUP BY
        LessonsAbsent.[Student ID],
        LessonsAbsent.[Class Number],
        LessonsAbsent.[Line Number],
        LessonsAbsent.[Year],
        LessonsAbsent.ClassDate
) results ON
    results.[Student ID] = allLessons.[Student ID]
    AND results.[Class Number] = allLessons.[Class Number]
    AND results.[Line Number] = allLessons.[Line Number]
    AND results.[Year] = allLessons.[Year]
    AND results.ClassDate = allLessons.ClassDate
```

Comment: Unfortunately that gives the same result as mine. The count doesn't reset when the student attended a lesson and missed the next.

Comment: Actually, after checking the results, it doesn't give the same result as mine as it skipped the entries where the student attended class, but continued the count at the next absent entry instead of resetting the count.

Comment: Sorry about that... I've corrected the logic, and validated that it gives the right answer this time.

Comment: Thank you, that was perfect :) Now if only I can find a way to speed it up. It's currently taking about 10 mins to run that Update query.

Comment: I've updated the query to try to make it more efficient.  Let me know if that works for you...  if so, up-votes are always appreciated. ;-)

Comment: Hi mfredrickson. Unfortunately that just made it take even longer! I think it's all the subqueries that's increasing the executing time.

Comment: What indexes do the tables have, and is that something that you're able to modify?

Comment: Hi mfredrickson. I modified the tables' indexes and was able to reduce the execution time :) Though it still take a long time since there are a lot of data

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
update L2
set L2.ConsecutiveAbs = 
        case 
        when L2.IsAbsent = 0 then 0
        else (  select  TOP 1 L1.ConsecutiveAbs 
                from    Lessons L1
                where   L2.[Student ID] = L1.[Student ID]
                    AND L2.[Class Number] = L1.[Class Number]
                    AND L2.[Line Number] = L1.[Line Number]
                    AND L2.[Year] = L1.[Year]
                    AND L2.ClassDate > L1.[ClassDate]
                ORDER BY L1.ClassDate desc
              )
        end as ConsecutiveAbs
from    Lessons L2
```

Edit:
Add your update around.

Edit2: Added the update

Comment: Hi Johan. Your suggested solution resulted in an error when I tried to run it. I did add the update around it. "Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression."

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you are looking to stick to the subquery idea.  This problem type -IMO -is better solved (quicker, less complex) using cursors.   Here is what the SQL would look like if you choose to go that route.

So didn't let me to paste the code in the answer.  So I've pasted the code snippet here.   http://pastebin.com/ybesdX2G

Here's a reference to the article showing you how to do cursors. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180169.aspx

Edit:
The cursor approach works on one row at a time and remembers whether the last row was absent/present.   So sorting the data correctly is important.

Notice that there is no ORDER BY in the code snippet.   I tested the code snippet against data sample you had provided in the question.   Your data was pre-sorted.  So, it worked like a charm.

In your database if your data isn't stored in a pre-sorted fashion(which I doubt it is) you will want to add an ORDER BY to line #8, to sort the data into the sequence.

Hope this helps.

Comment: You must do everything you can to avoid going to the dark-side of cursors while there's still a shimmer of hope for a set-based solution...

Comment: :-).  I subscribe to the same philosophy.  But not all operations are set based operations.  The OPs question is an example of an operation that isn't set based.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I haven't use cursor before so I will need to take some time to play around with it :)

Comment: After reading through the msdn definition, I don't think cursor will work for what I'm trying to do :( If I could move away from subquery then I would as it produces too much overhead and takes about 11 mins to update ~50,000 rows.

Comment: Hi Nareen. Thank you for the snippet. I did try it to see if it will work. Unfortunately the absence count doesn't reset when the student attend a lesson :(

Comment: Is it possible that you are not sorting the data when you are trying this?   I've edited the answer, with reason for sorting.

Comment: Ah, thank you for that Naraen :) When I posted the data, I had a ORDER BY Date in it, that's why the data was so nicely sorted. In actual fact, the data I work with is not sorted at all! I will add an ORDER BY to line 8 and let you know how it goes :) Remember though, I have 59000+ rows in that table and that is just going to increase as the year go on.

Answer (score 0):

This may not be useful depending on your scenario but it may help you get to the solution

```
select * 
into #orderedlessons
from Lessons
order by [Student ID], [Class Number], [Line Number], [Year], [ClassDate]

declare @tot int
set @tot=0
update #orderedlessons
set @tot = ConsecutiveAbs = Case when IsAbsent=0 then 0 else @tot+1 END;

update lessons
set lessons.ConsecutiveAbs = ordered.ConsecutiveAbs
from lessons inner join  #orderedlessons ordered on
lessons.[Student ID] = ordered.[Student ID]
and lessons.[Class Number] = ordered.[Class Number]
and lessons.[Line Number] = ordered.[Line Number]
and lessons.[Year] = ordered.[Year]
and lessons.ClassDate = ordered.[ClassDate]

drop table #orderedlessons
```